# jquery change attribute

Tags: jquery, attributes, href, rel

i have 4 links and i need to change the href attribute in a rel attribute.
i know i cannot do it so i'm trying to get the data from the href attribute, setting a new attribute (rel), inserting the data inside it and then removing the href attibute.

basically i'm doing this:

```
$('div#menu ul li a').each(function(){
        var lin = $(this).attr('href');
        $('div#menu ul li a').attr('rel',lin);
        $(this).removeAttr('href');


        })
    })
```

it works but it sets the same rel data in every link i have.

any help?

Comment: `$('div#menu ul li a')` === `$(this)` inside your anonymous function, and you've two sets of closing braces and parenthesis.

Comment: i didn't even notice the extra "})". man... i need to eat or sleep.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('div#menu ul li a').each(function(){
    var lin = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('rel',lin);
    $(this).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('div#menu ul li a').each(function(){
    var lin = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('rel',lin);
    $(this).removeAttr('href');


    })
})
```

Haven't actually ran the code...but that looks like it should do the trick.

Comment: looks like I've been beaten! +1 to you.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$('div#menu ul li a').attr('rel',lin);
```

To:

```
$(this).attr('rel',lin);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably doing "it" wrong. (meaning there is a better way to do what you are attempting).

but to just answer your question:

```
$('#menu ul li a').each(function(){
    var lin = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).attr('rel',lin).removeAttr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solid jquery solution:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.selector").on("click", function() {
        var trigger = $(this.hash);
        trigger.removeAttr("id");
        window.location.hash = this.hash;
        trigger.attr("id", this.hash.replace("#",""));
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem

```
$('div#menu ul li a').attr('rel',lin);
```

this line apply changes to any element matches your selector, which in your case 
will match the four links
--use this code instead

```
$('div#menu ul li a').each(function(){
        var lin = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('rel',lin);
        $(this).removeAttr('href');    
        })
    })
```