# how to get value from javascript variable in href attribute of anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is very basic question, please excuse me for this.
I have a javascript code which detects mobile OS and generates URL accordingly. Here is the code:

```
//iPhone Version:
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    var url = "http://example.com/IWd7J";
}
//Android Version:
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/android/i)) {
    var url = "http://example.com/1K1Hi";
}
```

Now I want that URL in various href attributes of anchor tags in the page.

```
<a href="">Click Here</a>
```

Please suggest me a way.

Comment: Have you tried searching this on internet. You will get 1000s of result.Use `setAttribute` function. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery change attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654328/jquery-change-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the href of a elements use [`jQuery.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) like this:

```
$("a").attr("href", url);
```

This will select all the anchors in the document. If you want to narrow the selection use one of these [**CSS Selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: This should not be an answer, but comment. p.s. I'm not the downvoter

Comment: And why should it be a comment not an answer??

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy Nope, it should be a full answer, **not** a comment.